How to implement firebase crashlytics in React Native?
I am working on a react native library for a client. It can be seamlessly integrated into any React Native application. The client has Firebase analytics and crashlytics already set up. I want to detect any crashes in the client's application due to my library or anything else.
I attempted to integrate Firebase Analytics into my library, but after considerable effort, it finally gave this error:
Error: You attempted to call "firebase.app('NAME_OF_MY_LIBRARY').analytics but; analytics does not support multiple Firebase Apps.
I want to know if I can implement crashlytics in my library. If yes, then how can I do that?

Go to the Firebase Console (https://console.firebase.google.com/) and create a new project.
Follow the instructions to add Firebase to your Android and iOS apps. You'll need to provide your app's package name (Android) and bundle ID (iOS).
Download the google-services.json file for Android and GoogleService-Info.plist file for iOS, and place them in the appropriate directories in your React Native project.

npm install @react-native-firebase/app @react-native-firebase/crashlytics
cd ios && pod install && cd ..


Import Firebase in your index.js or App.js file:

import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import { name as appName } from './app.json';
import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app';

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp();
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);

Import Crashlytics in the file where you want to use it:

import crashlytics from '@react-native-firebase/crashlytics';
crashlytics().log('This is a log`enter code here` message');
crashlytics().recordError(new Error('This is a non-fatal error'));
crashlytics().crash();

